# How to redirect stderr and stdout to different files in the same line in script?

Tags: linux, bash

I know this much:

```
$ command 2>> error

$ command 1>> output
```

Is there any way I can output the stderr to the error file and output stdout to the output file in the same line of bash?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Just add them in one line `command 2>> error 1>> output`

However, note that `>>` is for appending if the file already has data. Whereas, `>` will overwrite any existing data in the file.

So, `command 2> error 1> output` if you do  not want to append.

Just for completion's sake, you can write `1>` as just `>` since the default file descriptor is the output. so `1>` and `>` is the same thing.

So, `command 2> error 1> output` becomes, `command 2> error > output`

Comment: Great answer! I really like your explanation of how `1>` can be written as `>`

Comment: How is this different from like `command &2>err.log`, I think i am totally confusing sintaxies. (A link to an appropriate answer of all the bash pipe-isms might be in order)

Comment: @ThorSummoner http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html is what I think you're looking for. Fwiw, looks like `command &2>err.log` isn't quite legit -- the ampersand in that syntax is used for file descriptor as target, eg `command 1>&2` would reroute stdout to stderr.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn, please don't link the ABS as a reference -- it occasionally contains outright inaccuracies, and very frequently contains bad-practice examples. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial is a *far* better reference source on redirection.

Comment: Shouldn’t standard output be always redirected first, before standard error is redirected??

Comment: @reportaman - The order does not matter, unless there you are redirecting one descriptor to another for example 2>&1, In this case you need to redirect 1 first

Comment: The next previous question is correct (at least on Mac). You have to put the redirection of stderr (i.e. 2) after the redirection of stdout. At least I do, at least on Mac. It took me hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
your_command 2>stderr.log 1>stdout.log
```

## More information

The numerals `0` through `9` are *file descriptors* in bash. 
`0` stands for standard input, `1` stands for standard output, `2` stands for standard error. `3` through `9` are spare for any other temporary usage.

Any file descriptor can be redirected to a file or to another file descriptor using the operator `>`. You can instead use the operator `>>` to appends to a file instead of creating an empty one.

Usage:

```
file_descriptor > filename

file_descriptor > &file_descriptor
```

Please refer to [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: Thanks.i searching this for one hour

Answer (score 12):

Like that:

```
$ command >>output 2>>error
```

Answer (score 8):

Or if you like to mix outputs (stdout & stderr) in one single file you may want to use:

```
command > merged-output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Why do people merge outputs or suggest merging outputs?

Comment: @nurettin: maybe you a have a script line that just executes a command and instantly saves the output to a log file. The command in question may fail sometimes so you want to save any errors about that too but to the same log file.

Comment: @streamofstars yes of course you are right maybe sometimes that is what people want, I was commenting within the context of this question as someone who was seeking answers and found a lot of irrelevant ones all over stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple commands' output can be redirected.  This works for either the command line or most usefully in a bash script.  The `-s` directs the password prompt to the screen.

Hereblock cmds stdout/stderr are sent to seperate files and nothing to display.

```sh
sudo -s -u username <<'EOF' 2>err 1>out
ls; pwd;
EOF
```

Hereblock cmds stdout/stderr are sent to a single file and display.

```sh
sudo -s -u username <<'EOF' 2>&1 | tee out
ls; pwd;
EOF
```

Hereblock cmds stdout/stderr are sent to separate files and stdout to display.

```sh
sudo -s -u username <<'EOF' 2>err | tee out
ls; pwd;
EOF
```

Depending on who you are(whoami) and username a password may or may not be required.