# Redirect stderr and stdout to separate files in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am able to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to separate files using:

```
dir >> out 2>> error
```

or `stderror` and `stdout` together to a single file using:

```
dir >> consolidate 2>&1
```

How can I do this together (get out, error, consolidate files at a time)?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/3076724)?

Comment: @BroSlow I'm looking for more than that . .something like . . ls 2>>(tee error | tee -a consolidated ) && 1>>( tee out | tee -a consolidated)

Comment: Why can't you simply `cat out err >>consolidate` afterwards?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: concatenating afterwards discards the relative order of the lines.

Comment: ...not just "afterwards", but even recombining later in a running pipeline discards (some) ordering information. Guarantees that ordering between stdout and stderr is precisely in line with the write calls only exist when they're both served by the same file descriptor, and you can't have them served by the same file descriptor while directing their output to different places, even if they're recombined later.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: stderr is unbuffered, stdout is fully buffered then redirected. The order is already lost

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I agree that the ordering is not strictly maintained due to buffering, but some interleave will probably occur that may be useful, and that will definitely be lost if the files are concatenated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr and stdout to different files in the same line in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901517/608639)

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like:

```
(command > >(tee out.txt) 2> >(tee error.txt >&2)) &> consol.txt
```

**Test:**

```
$ ls
f
```

```
$ ls g*
ls: cannot access g*: No such file or directory
```

```
$ (ls g f > >(tee out.txt) 2> >(tee error.txt >&2)) &> consol.txt
```

```
$ cat out.txt
f
```

```
$ cat error.txt
ls: cannot access g: No such file or directory
```

```
$ cat consol.txt
f
ls: cannot access g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest a simpler `{ command > >(tee out.txt) 2> >(tee err.txt); } > both.txt` but it doesn't work (`tee out.txt` receives output from `tee err.txt`) i.e., the redirection to stderr is necessary: `{ command > >(tee out.txt) 2> >(tee err.txt >&2);} &> both.txt`

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for any bashisms, as this can easily be done in standard sh:

```
{ { dir | tee -a out; } 2>&1 >&3 | tee -a error; } >> consolidate 3>&1
```

Comment: +1 -- but with the caveat that, like every other available approach short of writing your "dir" command to log to multiple sinks itself, this doesn't guarantee correct ordering.