# Logging stdout and stderr of Node

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am using the boilerplate code of [mean.io](http://mean.io) and starting my server with the command:

```
node server.js
```

How do I log `stdout` and `stderr` of my Express application?

Here's my file `server.js`:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    logger = require('mean-logger');

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Initializing system variables
var config = require('./server/config/config');
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);

// Bootstrap Models, Dependencies, Routes and the app as an express app
var app = require('./server/config/system/bootstrap')(passport, db);

// Start the app by listening on <port>, optional hostname
app.listen(config.port, config.hostname);
console.log('Mean app started on port ' + config.port + ' (' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ')');

// Initializing logger
logger.init(app, passport, mongoose);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: What do you mean `log`? All output goes to STDOUT_FILENO already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr and stdout to different files in the same line of bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901517/how-to-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-different-files-in-the-same-line-of-bash)

Comment: If you want to keep your logs then I am assuming logs are somehow valuable to you. I will recommend using some higher level logging package like Winston (https://github.com/flatiron/winston) instead of console.log which writes to stdout.

Comment: To understand more about loggin in node.js, please refer to this excellant article - http://devgigs.blogspot.in/2014/01/mastering-nodejs-logging.html

Answer (score 86):

What about this?

```
console.log("I will goto the STDOUT");
console.error("I will goto the STDERR");
```

**Note:** both of these functions automatically add new line to your input.

If you don't want those newlines appended to your input, do this

```
process.stdout.write("I will goto the STDOUT")
process.stderr.write("I will goto the STDERR")
```

Both `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` are streams, so you can even pipe a stream into them. See [Node.js docs on streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) for more info.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this by writing to stdout and stderr streams

```
process.stdout.write('Hello')
```

or

```
process.stderr.write('Error')
```

Better will be to use some thirdparty logging module like [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) or [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan)

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of to do this is to spawn a `child process` (like the fork system call), which then you can "pipe" the output of `stderr`, `stdout` to files.

```
var out = fs.openSync('./output.log', 'a')
  , err = fs.openSync('./error.log', 'a');

require('child_process').spawn('./server', [], {
    detached    : true,
    stdio       : ['ignore', out, err]
});
```