# How to write node errors to stderr

Tags: node.js, shell, runtime-error, sh

I'm running a node app via a shell script

```
#STARTUP.sh
node server.js

#/etc/rc.local  - this runs on startup of my machine
sudo sh startup.sh >> /home/pi/logs/app.log 2>&1
```

My issue is, when I have an error in my node app it just crashes and doesn't write the error to app.log

Is there a way to make sure when the app crashes that the error gets logged as well?

Comment: Are you properly catching exceptions? Maybe this post can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7313005/3558900

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861917/logging-stdout-and-stderr-of-node

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` in `rc.local`? Does that log file exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last line with this:

```
sudo sh startup.sh &>>/home/pi/logs/app.log
```