# Write stderr and stdout to one file, but also write stderr to a separate file

Tags: linux, shell, io, scripting

I have a shell script whose stdout and stderr I want to write to a logfile. I know that this can be achieved via

```
sh script.sh >> both.log 2>&1
```

However, I also want to simultaneously write the stderr to a separate file, "error.log". Is this achievable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect stderr and stdout to different files in the same line of bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901517/how-to-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-different-files-in-the-same-line-of-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to first switch stdout and stderr, which requires an additional file descriptor:

```
sh script.sh 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-
```

The last operator closes the auxiliary file descriptor.

After that you can use `tee` to duplicate the error stream (which is now on stdin) and append it to your error log:

```
sh script.sh 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee -a error.log
```

And after that you can then direct both stdin and stderr to your combined log:

```
(sh script.sh 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee -a error.log) >> both.log 2>&1
```

The parentheses around the command are important to capture the error stream of the whole command. Without them only the (empty) error stream of the `tee` command would be captured and the rest would still go to the terminal.

Note: this does not check wheater the file descriptor 3 was in use (open) before. In bash you can use this to choose a previously unused file descriptor and close it on the last redirection:

```
sh script.sh {tmpfd}>&2 2>&1 1>&${tmpfd}-
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tee` to duplicate output to two locations. Combine that with some tricky redirections, and...

```
script.sh 2>&1 >> both.log | tee -a both.log >> error.log
```

This redirects stderr to stdout, and then stdout to `both.log`. stderr remains, and is piped to `tee`, which copies it to both log files.

Comment: I don't see how this keeps only std-err msgs in the `error.log` file. Aren't then mixed together with` 2>&1` (and indistinguishable). ?

Comment: If the order were swapped `>> both.log 2>&1` then they'd be mixed together. Redirections are counterintuitive. `2>&1` doesn't mean "stderr goes to stdout". It means "stderr goes to wherever stdout is going to". Think of it like variable assignment. `x = 5; y = x; x = 7;` -- the value of `y` is 5, not 7.

Comment: Ah, duh..Missed that the position of `2>&1` is swapped with standard practice. What a great trick! Tnx for reply.

Comment: How to keep stdout and stderr in console too?