# PHP exec ("javac file.java >> log.txt") does not write compile errors to file

Tags: java, php

I am writing a small php script that compiles java code using the exec function. I want the compile to fail and write compile issues to a log file but the log file doesn't contain anything when I cat it. How can I get compile error messages into that log file?

```
<?php 

 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

// When it doesn't compile, it doesn't write error to log.txt 
$class = 'class runrunrun
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
            FAIL NOW!!
        } 

    }'; 

    $myfile = fopen("runrunrun.java", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $class);
    fclose($myfile);

    exec("javac runrunrun.java >> log.txt", $foo, $compileFlag);
        if ($compileFlag != 0) {
            echo "COMPILE ERROR\n";
        }

?>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm trying to run this on an AFS Server. Here's the output from lsb_release. I hope this clears it up a bit

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch

Distributor ID: Scientific

Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.8 (Carbon)

Release:    6.8

Codename:   Carbon

The default shell is BASH

Comment: It's unclear what O/S and shell you're using.  If you are on a Mac or Unix box, at a guess you're using Bash in which case you'll want to do "javac runrunrun.java 2>&1 >> log.txt".  This redirects stderr to stdout.  Let us know more about your environment.

Comment: @stdunbar Thank you for pointing that out! I've updated the question for the info you asked. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to direct `STDERR` to a file using `2>>`.  You are currently only redirecting `STDOUT`.

```
javac runrunrun.java >> log.txt 2>> error.log
```

May work for you.

Or, as mentioned in another comment, redirect all output to the same file with `2>&1`

```
javac runrunrun.java 2>&1 log.txt
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901533/1301994).