# redirecting error to one file and stdout to another function and then another file

Tags: linux, bash

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901533/3512538) about redirecting `stdout / stderr` to different places by using `command 2>x 1>y`. 
However, I'm interested in manipulating the `stdout` part:

I want to `tar -xvzf` a file, count the output files, and store that in a file, and store the errors in another file.

**1st attempt:**

```
tar -xvzf pkg.tgz 2>err 1>output
```

the file names themselves are saved in `output` (I didn't use `wc -l`, but at least it gives a meaningful output)

**2nd attempt:**

```
tar -xvzf pkg.tgz 2>err 1 | wc -l >output
```

> tar: 1: Not found in archive
>
> > tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

How can I get number of files extracted OR failure indication if something went wrong (the `tar -xvzf` usually unpacks the files AND outputs the error)?

**3rd attempt:**

```
tar -xvzf pkg,tgz 2>err | wc -l > output
```

*kind of works, but I'm not sure about it...*

My question is: is my 3rd attempt legit? Also, is there an option that the redirection would create a file ONLY if it has data in it (i.e. if `stderr` has nothing, no err file will be created?)

Answer (score 1):

The `tee` command can help a lot in this situation. It is like a T junction on a road or pipework. Tee takes the std input, sends it to 1 or more files, and then also output to std output, which might have further filters, such as `wc`.

If you want to do further manipulation on the content before saving it to a file, then do it before the tee. If you want to do extra manipulation just on the file, then in bash, you can use >(command) instead of the filename.